# Can I use the Screen class in a background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screen, background-thread

Sucessfully using the [.NET class `Screen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) in a background thread in a WinForms application, I wondered wether this is well-defined behavior.

I'm currently reading the pixel dimensions of the primary screen like:

```
var w = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
var h = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

The reason why I'm wondering is that the WinForms classes tend to be [used from the foreground thread only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx), and I found no documentation stating whether the `Screen` class is safe from using in a background thread or not.

**So my question is:**

Is it OK to read the `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` property in a background thread?

**Update 1:**

Please note that my question is *not* about thread-safety. It is about accessing UI elements from a background thread.

E.g. using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net) I found that the methods internally use `ReleaseDC` which *might* be disallowed or caused undefined results when being called from a background thread.

**Update 2:**

Thanks for downvoting and flagging to close this question.

I still do think that this *might* be non-obvious, since:

- A background thread has no message pump and the `Screen` class might require one.
- The class lives in the System.Windows.Forms assembly which might indicate it requires special attention.

Comment: It is read-only, so I see no reason why not

Comment: Uhm there is the section `Thread Safety` in the same link you have posted. However, not every WinForms classes are unsafe in a background thread.

Comment: Funny: _Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe._ Now `Bounds` isn't but `GetBounds()` is.

Comment: PrimaryScreen is static

Comment: @TaW 99.99% of all of the types in .NET say the exact same thing.  That tells you basically nothing about how you should be using the type.

Comment: Please note that my question is _not_ about thread-safety! It is about accessing UI elements from a background thread.

Comment: @Steve And the members of the returned object are not, so it merely begs the question of whether the object returned from `GetBounds` can be accessed safely.

Comment: @UweKeim Which is a virtually identical question.  The whole point of marshaling UI objects to the UI thread is to make them thread safe, because they wouldn't be if you didn't.

Comment: `Screen` doesn't inherit from `Control` so why would they be related?

Comment: Well, the thing is. The Screen class is an UI object? It doesn't derive from Control so perhaps the rules for that class cannot be applied here

Comment: Screen isn't a UI object. It doesn't have any visual representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot trust the  .NET thread safety documentation, it is merely copy/pasta that was only ever is modified when it really mattered.  The most important property of a monitor is that it doesn't jump around on you.  There is no read-modify-write at play.

Using it in a thread is fine, the class is a *very* thin wrapper around the MonitorFromXxx() winapi functions.  The underlying DeviceIoControl calls are always safe, device drivers need to keep many processes happy.  Actually using the results in a meaningful way, well, maybe not.

Comment: Thanks, Hans, your answer really helps me a lot.

Comment: Hm, makes me wonder what happens when I switch the primary screen. Can't for not having a second one..